# Regular Expression for memory allocation in C#

Tags: c#, regex, ram

I need a regular expression for multiple numbers and only one alpha character. My goal is to get the regular expression for setting memory in a Java Virtual Machine using *-Xmx* and *-Xms* so it needs to pass the following strings:

```
-1024k
-512M
-8g
-2048m
```

So what needs to be done is that the regular expression pass numbers that are multiple of 1024 except if the letter is *g* or *G*.

This is the code i'm using now and is not even working. Will appreciate the help

```
(Regex.IsMatch(options[2], "\\d\\^[KkGgMm]$") ? options[2] : "");
```

Comment: `^` denotes the beginning of the line. So how can it be in the middle of the expression?

Comment: Note that it would be much easier to extract number and check its value with normal integer comparison...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps try:

```
(Regex.IsMatch(options[2], @"^-\d+[KkGgMm]$") ? options[2] : "");
```

Or if you really want to use regex to also validate the number (not advised, and it's has got limits too) you'll get something a bit like this:

```
(Regex.IsMatch(options[2], @"^-(?:\d+[Gg]|(?:128|256|512|1024|2056)[MmKk])$") ? options[2] : "");
```

Which will also match `-128m` (and similar with M, K and k), 256, 512, 1024 and 2056, but not higher.

Comment: Thanks, i guess i could validate the option on another method but this helped me.

Comment: @Halosecrets0032 Mhm. You could check for instance if the log of the number base 2 is an integer. If it is, then it's valid for m and k. 2**7 = 128, 2**8 = 256, etc.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Oops, I won't know why I sometimes am off by 4 units xD Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand what you want to achieve. Here is a regex that matches the number from the input string if it is in a form `-xL` (x is any number and L is any letter except for g or G):

```
^\-(\d+)[^Gg]\b
```

You will have your number ina capture group (if any)